# Difference between ar, tar, gzip, zip and when should I decide to choose which one?

Tags: tar, zip, gzip, archive

I had a use case where I needed to pack a bunch of files into one. And all above commands does the same. I know `gzip` **compresses** my files but lets say space is not at all an issue for me then in that case which one should I choose?

Now some would say you would save some time while transferring files on network using compression but unzipping and decompression compensates for the time that I would have saved in transfer. So basically I am unable to choose and decide which of the above tools to choose and when?

Comment: Use zip. /Closed gzip compresses individual files, it won't work for you. Tar and AR are not compressors.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you came to the conclusion that all those tool do the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I had a use case where I needed to pack a bunch of files into one

Ah, you need an *archive* of files

> And all above commands does the same.

Not at all! Some are archivers, some are compressors, some are decompressors, some a combination.

- `ar`: very archaic, use cases are *very* specific. Pretty certain you don't ever want to use `ar` yourself.
- `gzip` / `gunzip`: Not an archiver. Can take a single stream of data and compress it (or decompress it, in case of `gunzip`). You can use this *together* with an archiver. Gzip is very old and slow and inefficient, there's alternatives that achieve much higher compression or higher speed, or any mixture of that (e.g., `zstd`, `lz4`)
- `tar`: Short for *tape archiver*; a very common archiver that you can also tell to compress stuff. For example:

```
tar cf archive.tar file1 file2 file3
```

creates an *uncompressed* archive containing file1, file2 and file3. However, adding the `z` option to the `c`reate command (I know, `tar`'s syntax is hellish):

```
tar czf archive.tar.gz file1 file2 file3
```

will make `tar` use `gzip` internally and create a tar archive that's been compressed.
You can also just pipe the result through any compressor of your choice to get compressed archives, e.g.

```
tar cf - file1 file2 file3 | gzip > archive.tar.gz # or
tar cf - file1 file2 file3 | zstd > archive.tar.zst # or
tar cf - file1 file2 file3 | lz4 - archive.tar.xz # or
tar cf - file1 file2 file3 | xz > archive.tar.xz
```

You get the idea.
As common as `tar` is, it's a very old program and format(s), and it leaves a lot to be desired. But it does correctly deal with Linux file ownership, permissions, links, special files…

- `zip` is a compressing archiver. Works very nicely with windows, as well, but can not deal with file permissions. Hence, **not usable for backups!**
- `7z` is like zip, a compressing archiver, which cannot deal with user and permission information. Hence, **not usable for backups!**
- `mksquashfs` is a kind of an archiver, meant for very neatly packed archives, that can also be used like normal file systems. It can use modern, on request very fast or very strong compression.

> Now some would say you would save some time while transferring files on network using compression but unzipping and decompression compensates for the time that I would have saved in transfer.

And those people would be right! If you use a modern, speed-optimized compression, you'd be *faster* than reading or writing from an SSD with decompression. And much, much faster than your network would ever be (unless you are looking at datacenter-grade networking).

So, if *speed* is your concern, use something that makes use of a fast compressor. As said, `gzip` is probably not the compressor of choice in 2023, so

```
tar cf - srces/ | zstd -1 > archive.tar.zst
```

achieves an archival rate of roughly 3 Gb/s (in case you planned to put this through network, and thought the compressor would be a bottleneck) in my test that uses a mixture of source code, binary files. It makes 1.4 GB out of the original 4.97 GB. Using `-2` instead of `-1` makes the result another 10% smaller, and reduces the speed to 2.5 Gb/s. Which is still faster than most SATA SSDs could write. And this was single-threaded. Use `zstd -2 -T0` to make use of all CPU cores, and my humble PC does 6.5 Gb/s; `zstd -4 -T0` still does 2.5 Gb/s, so more than most of my network cards could do, and gets the size down to 1.2 GB :)

So:

- Need to archive files, but fast, for sending them to other people who might not have the same software as you? `tar cv - files… | zstd -4 -T0 > archive.tar.zst` is what you want
- Need to archive files, but strongly compressed, for sending them to other people who might not have the same software as you? `tar cv - files… | zstd -13 -T0 > archive.tar.zst` is slower, but gives very high compression ratios already.
- Need to archive files, want to read them later on, without having do un-archive things? `mksquashfs files… archive.squashfs -comp=zstd`; add `-Xcompression-level 4` to the end for higher speed at the expense of size.

The resulting `archive.tar.zst` files can be directly unarchived with modern GNU tar, `tar xf archive.tar.zst`; the `archive.squashfs` can either be mounted directly `udisksctl loop-setup -f archive.squashfs` and used like a DVD (i.e., you can directly browse the files on it), or de-archived using `unsquashfs archive.squashfs`

Comment: Great answer from you Marcus. I'd just add about *gzip* : "But being for ages widely spread amongst Xs". Since… well… at the end of the day, choosing your archiver / compressor first depends on the tools being (that will be) available when/where needing to un-archive / un-compress. Regarding the future… its some kind of bet with more or less chances to win it ;-)

Comment: @MC68020 thanks for the compliment! And, regarding availability: absolutely! That's partially the reason for my last paragraph: GNU tar on any Linux distro I've encountered in the last couple of years  has been built with zstd support enabled (at least on FreeBSD, the same is true for their bsdtar), so it is available by default, at least for single-threaded decompression. I honestly think gzip is obsolete!

Comment: Great answer thanks, I just wanted to mention zip command, not gunzip that was a mistake my bad

Comment: parallel gzip = [pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/) is using _old_ compression, but multithreaded, which might be of interest to all who make whole drive images stored somewhere

Comment: @VlastimilBurián yes, if you're for any reason bound to the gzip compression format, always use pigz when you can :) is by the zlib author and every good. But it really can't do much about the fact that gzip isn't a good compression standard by modern standards. Multi-threaded zstd is still faster than multi-threaded gzip at comparable compression ratios.